# How to create a webform submission table with values from the form itself?

Tags: 7, views, webforms, forms

I find the current webform submission table completely inadequate when forms are submitted by anonymous users - you can't tell one from another other than by its submission date which not helpful in many instances. I would like to create a new webform submission table that can display specific fields from the submission itself to help identify who the submission is from. Ideally if I could accomplish this with views that would be great, but I am not adverse to creating a module if need be. Has anyone done this before and what would be the best approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the current stable release of the Webform module doesn't support getting to any of the webform submission fields through Views.

However, if you look at this issue on Drupal.org: http://drupal.org/node/680386, you'll see that **integration with views** is a highly desired feature!  That's why there's so much activity on it!  The good news is that (look at this comment: http://drupal.org/node/680386#comment-6480250) there's actually a patch applied to version 7.x-4.0-alpha6 of the [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module, so you can test this new integration functionality.

Let us know if it works well!

Comment: That sounds very encouraging and I look forward to Weform 4's release but in the meantime with Webform 3, is it possible to use Webform Tokens to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Webform 4.X is the way to go if you want to use views.

If you are only trying to change the column headers/info (or don't want to upgrade to 4) you can use the provided hooks:
`theme_webform_results_table_header` & `theme_webform_results_table.`

Webform includes 'webform.api.php' in the module that doesn't include working code, but rather documents all of the hook usage in webform.

Comment: I am trying update the contents of the table itself, not the column headers. Is it possible to use webform tokens as a possible work around with Webform 3?